# Gradle, create a new jar from each sourceset

Tags: gradle

I have a sub project, first my files

the main projects gradle file:

```
defaultTasks 'assemble'
apply plugin: 'idea'

allprojects {
    //this brings all the compiled entities to one directory
    archivesBaseName = "mybase"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'scala'


    compileJava {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    compileScala{
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    jar {
        manifest.attributes provider: 'MyProcJar'
    }

    assemble{
        archivePath = file("${rootDir}/dist")
    }

    ext {
        springVersion = "3.2.1.RELEASE"
        springSecurityWebVersion = "3.1.3.RELEASE"
        springSecurityOauth2Version = "1.0.1.RELEASE"
        jacksonCoreVersion = "2.1.2"
    }

    dependencies {
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    }

    tasks.withType(AbstractArchiveTask){
        destinationDir = project.rootProject.file("dists")
    }
}
```

the subproject gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    gwt-graphics {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["java"]
            compileClasspath += main.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output
        }
    }

    login-controls {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["java"]
            compileClasspath += main.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output
        }
    }

    sample-app {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["java"]
            compileClasspath += main.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output
        }
    }

}
```

My project layout

```
mainproj/gwt/src/gwt-graphics/java:
mainproj/gwt/src/login-controls/java:
mainproj/gwt/src/sample-app/java:
```

In my subproject, i would like to have each element of the sourceset to be compiled into a separate jar file.  How do i do that?  at the moment i can't even get anything to compile.

Answer (score 2):

You should use valid (Groovy) identifiers for the source sets, and should point them to the correct source directories:

```
sourceSets {
    gwtGraphics {
        srcDirs = ["gwt-graphics/java"]
    }
}
```

The `java` plugin only adds a `jar` task for the `main` source set. You can add your own, either one by one or by "looping" over `sourceSets.all`. For more information, see the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) or the samples in the full Gradle distribution.

Some other hints:

- Instead of configuring `sourceSet.compileClasspath` and `sourceSet.runtimeClasspath` directly, you can do `dependencies { gwtGraphicsCompile sourceSets.main.output }` etc. Then you won't need to repeat the same configuration for the runtime class paths.
- Instead of setting source/target compatibility for each compile task, you can set it globally (e.g. `sourceCompatibility = 1.7`).
- Since extra properties are inherited, I'd move the `ext` block out of the `subprojects` block.

Comment: cool, thanks.  i will try that when i get home.  Is there a project that you know of that has a pretty complicated build system done in gradle that i could use as an example for further stuff?  thanks

Comment: Spring, Gradle, Spock, Geb, samples in the full Gradle distribution.